# Ajax in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have used jQuery mobile with ajax function. Ajax function return proper data but element style cannot be applied in return data.

```
function feedsearch()
{
    $.ajax ({
    url: "feed.php",
    cache: false,
    type:"get", 
    success: function(html)
    {
        //alert(html);
        $("#mainDiv").html(html);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you are trying to add style? Also, what is the value of `html`

Comment: I make index.php file and in this file i add css files and js files and this file i used function files at there i used above function for getting post data but style cannot apply in feed.php file's element

Comment: what do you wish to do? post your PHP code so that we can grab what you intend doing

Comment: <li data-icon="refresh"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="feedsearch()" data-ajax="false">Updates</a></li>
i used this line for calling feedsearch() function.
<div id="mainDiv">
            </div>
Above function display data in above div but style of element cannot display

Comment: @PareshGami ok, post the content of your `feed.php`

Comment: File contain is large which is not allowed to paste. In this file i get post by login user and display in mainDiv thats it

Comment: It will be difficult to help you since I don't know if the response from the PHP file is even correct. Moreover, are you not passing data to the PHP file?

Comment: Response is woked in bootstrap properly but not in jQuery Mobile

Comment: un-comment that `alert(html);` and see what it shows. If there is error, you will see it.

Comment: No its working proper in bootstrap. My problem is that in index.php jQuery reflect the element style but when i call ajax function for getting data like button's and textbox. so responsed data is not reflected by jQuery mobile means response is not styled

Comment: are you building a mobile apps or website? Does it return a visible respose that you see?

Comment: i will host it and see it

Comment: http://fexicol.com/mobile/

Comment: ok, you want to style the button?

Comment: Yes.!! index file's button is reflected automatically. but responsed button cannot not

Comment: From the page, the response is a button (that is a button is created dynamically). Is it the button you want to style and look like a normal button in JQuery Mobile?

Comment: feed.php have following code
<input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="feedsearch()">

Comment: Yes, and the code `<input type="button" value="Get Data" onclick="feedsearch()">` is added to `<div id="#mainDiv"></div>` without a problem. What do you want now?

Comment: In response get code of button this button is not styled by css files. i want to apply style in responsed button also like index file's button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok... put `<a id="button" data-role="button" onclick="feedsearch()">Get Data</a>` in your PHP file.

Then put this in your Javascript `$('[data-role="button"]').button();`

Complete code;

```
function feedsearch()
     {
          $.ajax ({
          url: "feed.php",
         cache: false,
         type:"get", 
         success: function(html)
         {

        //alert(html);
         $("#mainDiv").html(html);

          $('[data-role="button"]').button(); 

        }
         });
     }
```

Comment: It is not. Please explain me it in detail

Comment: why don't you use a <a id="button" data-role="button" onclick="feedsearch()">Get Data</a> . Put this in your php file

Comment: @PareshGami I have edited the code, it should now work. Try it again

Comment: glad I was able to help

Comment: after adding this line 
$('[data-role="button"]').button();
Toggle Button will be display in full screen. Please see this on http://prntscr.com/35ew2a

Comment: Where i want to add this class?

Comment: `<a id="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" data-role="button" onclick="feedsearch()">Get Data</a>` like this

Comment: Thank you very much for very quick reply @BlackPearl

Comment: Its working but other thing not proper styled when i use ajax so what i do for that. i want use ajax in jquery mobile. Please help me. :'(